# error in spelling

Tags: spelling

My latex template in teXstudio editor, unfortunately, has a wrong spelling procedure. Some words that are correct are shown as if they are typo!
For example, below line:

[image]

How can I remove the mistakes?

Comment: Spell checking is not part of LaTeX, but a editor-specific thing. What editor are you using?

Comment: since it is marking every word I assume you have a language other than English set, but this is unrelated to latex it is a feature of whichever editor you are using.

Comment: teXstudio is the editor

Comment: Do please consult the online help facility of the texstudio software package for advice on how to set the proper language.